# MySQL potential race condition with selects and inserts

Tags: php, mysql, race-condition

I'm having a hard time pinning down an issue I'm having. First, I have a table for an IVR that is essentially a queue of people to call; it looks like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | name | phone_number | has_called | type_of_call | date_called | other_meaningless_statuses |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The important bit there is the 'has_called_status'. When that status is equal to zero, that means a person hasn't been called, and appears in the queue for calling.

My IVR has multiple types of calls it can make, so it adds people to different lists (see type_of_call). My issue is that I'm adding these lists in order, with the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ub.name, ub.phone_number FROM user_base ub
INNER JOIN ivr_queue ivr ON ub.usercode = ivr.usercode
WHERE ub.needs_call = 1
AND ub.published = 1 AND ub.ready_status = 0 #not important
AND
(
    ivr.has_called != 0
    OR
    ivr.has_called IS NULL
) #important bit!
#optional list-specific statuses go here
```

The program flow is: delete all people in ivr_queue with has_called = 0 -> select people for a certain list -> insert list -> repeat select and insert for all lists

Where I'm running into trouble is that I'm getting duplicate entries between lists. Lists have occasionally overlapping criteria, and therefore have duplicates. To avoid this, I added the two ivr conditions in the above query to filter out duplicates in all but the first list, which should be the first list created.

I'm certain that the ivr conditions are being included in all my selects, and that the PHP script that manages the queries does one select, then one insert, and rinses and repeats. I'm also certain that there are not duplicate entries within a given list.

I apologize for the length and complexity of the question, I will give any additional information or clarification if necessary.

EDIT: the duplicates I'm getting look like this: List 1 has 10 name-phone number pairs, list 2 has 30 name-number pairs, two of the name-number pairs in each list are identical, and on further investigation are indeed the same entry from my database. Presumably once the first list is inserted into the database this shouldn't be an issue (given the ivr exclusion parameters)
EDIT: I will edit in my PHP if necessary, although it's quite verbose, since I wasn't aware of Zend PDO until after I built the code.

Comment: There's just one process doing all the selecting and updating? Then there can't be a race condition, since that requires multiple threads overlapping. Can you show an example of data flow, and the duplicates you're getting?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not really sure what you mean by data flow. I've edited for an example of the duplicates.

Comment: How does including the `ivr.has_called` conditions prevent duplicates? Where are you setting that column to 0 so the rows won't be selected multiple times? You said that you delete all rows with `has_called = 0`.

Comment: I delete all calls with has_called = 0, then I insert each list using has_called = 0. Every entry I insert will have has_called = 0 as it is a new call. Therefore once each list is entered in it should eliminate those calls from future lists.

Comment: Inserting a new entry with has_called = 0 doesn't remove the old entry that has has_called = 1. So the next time you make a list, you'll find that old entry again.

Comment: I should probably edit again; has_called = 1 is fine, has called anything above 0 is fine. The duplicate entries all have has_called = 0

Comment: Yes, please edit. Instead of describing what you're doing, show the code.